# How Can I Call Template in Same Component on Vue

Tags: vue.js, templates

My problem is, there are a few templates on a component. And I want to call on same component. For example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    [I WANT TO USE FIRST TEMPLATE]
  </div>


  <template>First</template> //First Template
  <template>Second</template> //Second Template
</template>
```

Comment: Should they be rendered conditionally? or at the same time? and why cant we resort to two different components?

Comment: Yes it should be rendered conditionally.

Comment: @AliBatuhanBayraktar how do you want them to be rendered?

Comment: make those templates into components and render conditionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ihsan Fajar Ramadhan's answer is one way of doing it. But, there is another better way of conditional rendering of components like below:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <button v-on:click="setSelected('comp1')">Comp1</button>
        <button v-on:click="setSelected('comp2')">Comp2</button>    
        <component :is="selected"></component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import comp1 from './comp1.vue';
import comp2 from './comp2.vue';
export default { 
    components : {
        'comp1' : comp1,
        'comp2' : comp2
    },
    data(){
        return {
            selected : 'comp1'
    },
    methods: {
        setSelected(tab){
            this.selected = tab;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to render them conditionally, you can use `v-if` directive. for the example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    [I WANT TO USE FIRST TEMPLATE]
  </div>


  <template v-if="fistCondition">First</template> //First Template
  <template v-else>Second</template> //Second Template
</template>
```

or

```
<template>
  <div>
    [I WANT TO USE FIRST TEMPLATE]
  </div>


  <template v-if="fistCondition">First</template> //First Template
  <template v-else-if="secondCondition">Second</template> //Second Template
</template>
```